# Vuejs watcher not reacting to prop's change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple `.vue` component in which there is one prop `request` and a watcher to watch this prop. If `request` is `true` then I call a method.

The problem is, my watcher is not reacting to the changes.

I have tried to make the code below work.

#### foobar.vue

```html
<template><div> ... </div></template>

<script>
export default {    
  // ... 
  props: {
    request: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false 
    }
  },
  watch: {
    request (state) {
      if(state) {
        // run some method
      }
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

I now call the component as (after requiring it)

```html
<template>
  <foobar :request="access"> </foobar> 

  <button @click="access = !access"> {{ access ? 'Turn off' : 'Turn on'}} </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return { access: false }
  },
  components: { foobar }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify the component works very well. I have no errors or syntax issues

Comment: Could you include the code where you use the component? Currently you've not included any code showing how the prop `request` is being passed.

Comment: If you don't show us how you use `<foobar>...</foobar>` we can not help you.

Comment: Make your watcher `immediate` or it will not get called if the prop is set when first mounted.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this ~ https://jsfiddle.net/0oacxr14/

Comment: Hi @Phil I checked your source which is similar to my code except that you are not returning the data {} as function like `return { access: false }` instead you have it as `data: {access: false }` I tried to change my code like yours but it says error: `data should return an ...` so you code is different

Comment: @skirtle Check the code ` <foobar :request="access"> </foobar> ` I am passing `access` which is a boolean to foobar, the component is `foobar.vue` as seen in my question, I only left the generic and irrelevant parts as the code works well except for this pro

Comment: `data` is not a function in my example because it's on the root Vue instance whereas yours is a component. This is not a concern. How exactly are you verifying your problem? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: FYI, here's the same example but using components ~ https://jsfiddle.net/w7zr9otg/

Answer (score 0):

Set the watcher to `immediate`.

```
watch: {
 request :
   immediate:true, 
    handler(state) {
      if(state){
      // run some method
      }
    }
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem, i will update my question